# How to initialise an array in a loop in java?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, optimization

I am taking the size of an array in a variable in a loop. Each time I have to assign the size of the array equal to that variable and then take integers equal to that size. For example:

```
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    variable = sc.nextInt();
    int []array = new int[variable];
    for(j = 0; j < variable; j++)
    {
        array[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Please provide me the most efficient method as I am new to java :)

Comment: why this first loop `for(i=0;i<N;i++)` ?

Comment: Would an ArrayList suffice?

Comment: "Please provide me the most efficient method as I am new to java :)" StackOverflow is not a website where you post a problem and get code in return. Please explain what is wrong with your current implementation and we might be able to help.

Comment: what's wrong with using the code you posted?

Comment: @YCF_L as i mentioned in question i want N variables and each time I want to make an array of size of that variable i.e., size of array equal to the variable and such N arrays.

Comment: @Turing85 , I am not asking for code snippet and I mentioned the fact that I am new to Java is because I want most optimum method for that and yes, StackOverflow is the site for sharing knowledge. If my question is not clear to you then please read my above comment !

Comment: so you want `N` number of arrays with size `variable`? Am I understanding your problem correctly?

Comment: Yes, @BillF you understood it somewhat correctly! But, I am asking the user for this variable N times , so there are N different variables . Each array has different size according to that variable which is inputted by the user.

Comment: @Alfran I'm assuming you want to keep these arrays outside the `for loop` after to do something with the numbers, correct? Cause right now every time you loop through the first for loop, the previous array is "deleted"

Comment: Yes, I am doing some operations on them after taking them as you understood correctly. Now, after the operation has been performed I want new variable and then an array of size equal to that variable. :)

Comment: And I want to do this N times!

Comment: @Alfran see YCF_L's answer. that should work for you.

Comment: But please stick to the Java Naming Conventions. `N` should be `n`.

Comment: Okay! I will keep that in mind in future. I am very grateful of you for teaching me that lesson.

Comment: Efficient???  Man hours or CPU cycle counting?  (which is more precious, with a given expected volume?)

Comment: In this case , it's about minimum CPU ticks and minimum time and space complexity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need something like this :

```
List<int[]> list = new ArrayList<>();//create a list or arrays
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    int variable = sc.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[variable];
    for (int j = 0; j < variable; j++) {
        array[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    list.add(array);//add your array to your list
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of arrays and initialize them on outer loop and add values to arrays using position `i` and `j`.

```
// initialize list with n, though you can also use 2D array as well
List<int[]> array = new ArrayList<>(n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
    variable = sc.nextInt();

    // create an array and add it to list
    array.add(new int[variable]);

    for (int j = 0; j < variable; j++) {
        // fetch the array and add values using index j
        array.get(i)[j] = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    variable = sc.nextInt();
    ArrayList array = new ArrayList(variable)
    for(j=0;j<variable;j++)
    {
        int input = sc.nextInt()
        array.add(input);
    }
}
```

If an ArrayList works, this is how I'd do it.

Comment: OP asks for array initialization, therefore this is no answer.